# My phone is missing whatsapp communication

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

What can I do to bring  back my whatsapp number? I was using  my friend  phone  to communicate  with my whatsapp number  and I forget to change and now she still have my whatsapp number and she continue to receive message.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your WhatsApp account is registered on a different device, while using your number, you can easily reclaim your account, as long as you can receive text messages on that phone number.

Download [WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp) on your phone, register your account with your number, and it will automatically close the account on your friends phone.

---

On a side note, if you're looking to transfer all your messages from your friends phone to your phone, you can [transfer](https://www.fonepaw.com/solution/transfer-whatsapp-messages-android-to-android.html) the local backup from that phone, to yours.

Comment: And remember to take backup from your friend's mobile before installing on your device if you haven't selected to backup automatically on google drive.

Comment: @parthu_panther it will not help to select backup to Google drive, cuz both phones have to be under the same Google account. But a local backup will definitely help